# Datatable DT package R - embedd in ppt

Tags: r, dt

I'm using the amazing package `DT` in order to display interactive table.
Is there a way to embed table created with this package in a powerpoint presentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

HTML widgets [will be converted to static screenshots](https://yihui.name/en/2018/06/html-widgets-non-html/) if the output format is not HTML and you have installed the **webshot** package as well as PhantomJS:

```
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

The detailed documentation about this feature can be found in [Section 2.10 of the **bookdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html).

With static screenshots, obviously you cannot interact with the **DT** tables.

Answer (score 1):

if you use RStudio, you can try to produce a .Rpres file, selecting:

> File>>New File >> R presentation

If you really need a `.pptx` you can have a look at `ReporteRs` package.
However the DT packages creates interactive tables, so I suppose that the only way is to create an `html` file, using `Knitr` or find a way to embed `html` in `.pptx`, and I think that it should be possible. If it is not necessary the .pptx format, using R you can create great `html` file with interactive objects like `DT` outputs.

**EDIT:**
looking at the comments, you can use `rmarkdown` for PowerPoint and `ReporteRs` should not be used.

Comment: FYI, PowerPoint can be generated from R Markdown now: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/powerpoint-presentation.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: FYI ReporteRs should not be used anymore (issue with java >= 9) and officer should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try eoffice

```
install.package("eoffice")
```

Comment: Hi bioguo, while this answer may help with the opening poster's problem, it would likely be even more helpful if you provide more explanation, code, and / or images that demonstrate the solution.